# mysqladmin - Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to a mysql server over a local network. The server is running and listening to post 41322.

```
dylan~$ netstat -ln | s mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     41322    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

My user is granted all rights from all addresses, and I can log in locally.

```
dylan~$ mysqladmin -P 41322 -h dylan@10.0.0.10 create database test
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'dylan@10.0.0.10' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host 'dylan@10.0.0.10' (1)'
Check that mysqld is running on dylan@10.0.0.10 and that the port is 41322.
You can check this by doing 'telnet dylan@10.0.0.10 41322'
```

Adding a --verbose flag gives no additional output. I've commented out `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on the server. I can ssh into the server without a problem.

```
dylan~$ ps a | grep mysql
11131 pts/3    S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
11170 pts/3    Sl     0:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
11171 pts/3    S      0:00 logger -p daemon.err -t mysqld_safe -i -t mysqld
13710 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep mysq
```

Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `user@host` syntax is valid. Try `-h host -u user -p pass`

Comment: you `netstat` line indicates that mysql is listening on a `unix` socket (pipe), not a TCP socket. `41322` is an inode number in that case, not a TCP port.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your mysql daemon is not listening on a TCP port. Your netstat output shows that mysql is listening on a UNIX domain socket at inode 41322 (file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock).

You didn't mention your OS, but I'm assuming Linux by your use of the -l flag to netstat. To show all listening TCP and UDP ports and the daemons using them on Linux, run `netstat -ltunp`

Some default MySQL installs have "skip-networking" in the config file, usually /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Comment that option out if it's present and restart the daemon.